# Postgresql: foreign key to role oid

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

How can I add a foreign key to a database role in postgres?

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."role_info" (
    "last_login" timestamptz,
    "user" name,
    CONSTRAINT "role_info" FOREIGN KEY ("user") REFERENCES "pg_catalog"."pg_authid" ("rolname") ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
 )
 WITH (OIDS=FALSE);
```

This is returning *permission denied*.

Answer (score 7):

You don't. You can't add foreign keys that reference system catalogs in the current implementation.

Even if that restriction is relaxed later for some catalogs, global catalogs like `pg_role` that're shared by all DBs are likely to remain restricted.

You *can* use a trigger to unidirectionally enforce the relationship, stopping you from adding a value that references a non-existent system catalog entry. However, you can't stop the catalog entry being deleted, so it's only of limited utility.

**Edit 2019 around PostgreSQL 12 release:**

There are lots of reasons you can't do this.

The system special-cases system catalog relations in a number of ways that make them behave specially:

- It does in-place updates on them sometimes, which aren't allowed for user relations and cannot be rolled back on transaction abort
- It generally accesses them through a layer of indirection and caching (the syscache and relcache)
- It updates them via a special lightweight access method (genam) that doesn't support a bunch of PostgreSQL's higher level features and makes a number of simplifying assumptions for performance, memory use and code complexity reasons.

Furthermore in the case of `pg_catalog.pg_authid` it is a *shared relation* as you can see by checking `select relisshared from pg_catalog.pg_class where oid = 'pg_catalog.pg_authid'::regclass`. That means the same table contents are mapped into all databases on a PostgreSQL instance ("cluster" or data directory). There's no sensible way to have a FK to that, because the relation that's referencing it would only exist in the `pg_catalog.pg_class` of *one database* and so would the heap containing its rows - but the *referenced* `pg_catalog.pg_authid` heap would be mapped into *all databases*. A postgres backend connected to one db would have no idea the FK constraint even existed on another DB and no way to check.

Comment: Hi Craig, do you know if this restriction is changed in the recent releases (v11, v12)?
Is there a place where this is documented/explained in more detail?

Comment: No, it has not changed. I am not aware of anywhere that documents it in more detail, but there may be source code comments that do. I haven't looked closely at that area.  **I have edited to add an explanation of some of the reasons based on what I already know from other work**.